# Finding duplicate documents in BLOB field of Oracle table (Oracle Text)

Tags: sql, oracle, text, duplicates, documents

I need to somehow detect duplicate documents (.doc, .pdf, etc) which are stored in BLOB field of my table.

I've been looking into Oracle Text functionality, but failed to find something that can help me in achieving my goal.

In fact, i need something like UTL_MATCH functionality but with possible comparison of entire document in file.

Can someone provide me any tips on how to do that?

EDIT:
I'm not searching for absolutely same duplicates, which can be done through file comparison, I need to analyse text in documents, that's why I'm trying to use Oracle Text.

Comment: If you are uploading files and storing the file's name does checking if the filenames match not good enough? Alternatively have you tried looking at [`DBMS_LOB.COMPARE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1016668)

Comment: Nope, could use that approach, but documents can have different filenames, so the entire idea is to detect duplicate contents of file through text analysis.

Comment: Duplicate as in byte-for-byte,or just text.  One possible option is to run the blob bytes through a 32-bit CRC calculation, and compare the results.

Comment: Comparing as byte-for-byte is actually not my task here. What I'm trying to achieve is to get some percentage of matching based on text contents and treat document like "duplicate" if that percentage is over 98% for example.